# Show hidden div on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I have a html form with two bottons.  One is the main form submit another is a file upload.

I want to reveal a hidden div on the form submit, which works but it also reveals the hidden div when you click the file upload button, which I dont want.

Also if I click in any form field for text entry the div is revealed....

How can I get the hidden only to reveal on the main submit button

Here's the form

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/directory/submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onclick="showHide()"/>

<label>Tel
<span class="small">Contact Telephone No.</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="submitted_telephone" value="[var.submitted_telephone;htmlconv=no]"/>

<label>email*
<span class="small">Contact email</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="submitted_email" value="[var.submitted_email;htmlconv=no]"/>

<label>Address
<span class="small">Postal Address</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="submitted_address" value="[var.submitted_address;htmlconv=no]"/>

<label for="file">Filename
<span class="small">Upload image</span>
</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">

<div class="spacer"></div>
<button type="submit" title="Submit Details">Submit</button>
<input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="yes"/>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<div id="loading" style="display:none">
<img src="[var.base_url]/directory/style_images/Animated_Loading_Gif.gif" />
</div>

</form>
```

here's the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide() {
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `onclick` is wrong. It should be `onsubmit`

Comment: how did i miss that!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is wrong. It should be `onsubmit`. Also you have closing `/>` tag, remove `/` from `<form>` tag.

Change

```
<form onclick="showHide()"/> //wrong
```

To this

```
<form onsubmit="showHide()">
------^^^^^^^^------------^^
```